# DatagramPacket Equivalent

Tags: c#, java, datagram

What is a equivalent for this java code in c#

```
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(output,output.length,pack.getAddress(),pack.getPort());
socket.send(dp);
```

where pack - DatagramPacket, and socket - DatagramSocket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) provides User Datagram Protocol (UDP) network services.

> The UdpClient class provides simple methods for sending and receiving connectionless UDP datagrams in blocking synchronous mode. Because UDP is a connectionless transport protocol, you do not need to establish a remote host connection prior to sending and receiving data. You do, however, have the option of establishing a default remote host in one of the following two ways:
>
> - Create an instance of the UdpClient class using the remote host name and port number as parameters.
> - Create an instance of the UdpClient class and then call the Connect method.

And:

> [`Send(Byte[], Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k.aspx)    Sends a UDP datagram to a remote host.

Or alternatively:

> [`Send(Byte[], Int32, IPEndPoint)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82dxxas0.aspx)    Sends a UDP datagram to the host at the specified remote endpoint.

This last one more closely matches your example code.